# cant get another column data from datatable using onclick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

i have a problem in my script the ids and amount has a value while my Identitytype is null. im using onclick function to get all selected values based on specific column in datatable.

```
 $(function () {
        $('#PayableList').DataTable({
            "columnDefs": [{ type: 'date', 'targets': [6] }],
            "aaSorting": [[6, "desc"]],
            "ajax": "@Url.Action("getpayablelist", "payable")",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return "<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' onclick='add(" + full.Id + ", " + full.Amount + ", " + full.IdentityType + ", this.checked)'>"
                    }
                },
                { "data": "Name" },
                { "data": "ReferenceNo" },
                { "data": "IdentityType" },
                { "data": "Amount" },
                { "data": "CustomerPayable" },
                { "data": "CreatedDate" }
            ]
        });
    });

    var ids = [];
    var amounts = [];
    var identities = [];
    function add(id, amount, IdentityType, isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            ids.push(id);
            amounts.push(amount);
            identities.push(IdentityType);
        }
        else {
            var i = ids.indexOf(id);
            ids.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3XRZ.png)

Comment: Can you include sample data as well you are binding data table to?

Comment: @DipenShah see the link above for sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see actual type of data rom the image, but I am assuming `IdentityType` is string and hence causing an issue. Update render method to:

```
"render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
    return "<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' onclick='add(" + full.Id + ", " + full.Amount + ", \"" + full.IdentityType + "\", this.checked)'>"
}
```

and it should work. You are not escaping string in the method due to which problem is happening.

Check this really bad practice code to see effect on your current code after change:

```js
let full = {
  Amount: 100.25,
  Id: 1,
  IdentityType: "SOMERANDOMTEXT"
};
document.body.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' onclick='add(" + full.Id + ", " + full.Amount + ", \"" + full.IdentityType + "\", this.checked)' />";

function add(id, amount, identityType) {
  console.log(`${id}, ${amount}, ${identityType}`);
}
```